# How to iterate through a list with different start and stop indices in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```py
nums = [2, 4, 5, 3, 6]
a = [64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 56, 56, 56, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 66, 66, 66]
```

I want to iterate through the list `a` using the `nums` list. The first time, I want to iterate through the first two digits of a because that's the first number in `nums`. Then, I want to iterate through the next four elements in `a` since that's the second element in `nums` and so on.

Basically, iterate through [0, 2], [2, 4+2], [4+2, 4+2+5], [4+2+5, 4+2+5+3] of `a`. The numbers in `nums` are the number of elements I want to iterate through in `a`.

I then want to get the majority of the elements in `a` within that start and stop index. So, I did this:

```py
li = []
start = 0
stop = nums[0]

for j in range(len(nums)):
    for item in itertools.islice(labels, start, nums[j]):
        li.append(item)
        c = Counter(li)
        c.most_common()
        value, count = c.most_common()[0]
print(value)
```

How do I change the start and stop indices though? Thanks!

Comment: In my code, the list, labels, equals a.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired result/output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, using an iterator to read items from `a` instead of trying to figure out the indices?

```
nums = [2, 4, 5, 3, 6]
a = [64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 56, 56, 56, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 66, 66, 66]

aa = iter(a)
try:
    for n in nums:
        li = [next(aa) for _ in range(n)]
        # do whatever with these few elements
except StopIteration:
    # the contents of `nums` exceeded the length of `a`
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a re-write of the @GreenCloakGuy's asnwer.

You can write a generator which yields chunks like:

```py
def get_slices(iterable, numbers):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for n in numbers:
        yield [next(it) for _ in range(n)]
```

The above will raise exception if you put incorrect values in `numbers`. If this is not your case you can have an option to silent it like what [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) does:

```py
def get_slices(iterable, numbers, silent=True):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for n in numbers:
        if silent:
            try:
                yield [next(it) for _ in range(n)]
            except StopIteration:
                return
        else:
            yield [next(it) for _ in range(n)]
```

test:

```py
def get_slices(iterable, numbers, silent=True):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for n in numbers:
        if silent:
            try:
                yield [next(it) for _ in range(n)]
            except StopIteration:
                return
        else:
            yield [next(it) for _ in range(n)]


nums = [2, 4, 5, 3, 6]
a = [64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 56, 56, 56, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 66, 66, 66]

for i in get_slices(a, nums, silent=True):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
[64, 64]
[64, 64, 64, 56]
[56, 56, 63, 63, 63]
[63, 63, 64]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight modification to your code that changes the start and stop indices as you've asked:

```py
import itertools
from collections import Counter

nums = [2, 4, 5, 3, 6]
a = [64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 56, 56, 56, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 66, 66, 66]

li = []
start = 0
stop = nums[0]

for j in range(len(nums)):
    for item in itertools.islice(a, start, stop):
        li.append(item)
        c = Counter(li)
        c.most_common()
        value, count = c.most_common()[0]
    if j + 1 < len(nums):
        start = stop
        stop = nums[j + 1]
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use `itertools.accumulate`, as you're trying to iterate through the list in partial-sum indices, something like this should work:

```py
import itertools
from collections import Counter

for start, end in zip([0] + nums, itertools.accumulate(nums)):
    c = Counter(a[start:end])
    print(c.most_common()[0][0])  # This is the value
```

The `zip(...)` operation allows you to iterate pairs of start-stop indices, and the `[0]` at the beginning ensures that the first slice you iterate through is `[0, nums[0]]`

Comment: You forgot to accumulate for `start`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the slices with `itertools.islice`:

```
it = iter(a)
for num in nums:
    print(*islice(it, num))
```

Or without:

```
i = 0
for num in nums:
    print(a[i : (i := i+num)])
```

Respective outputs ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BCsIwDIbvfYr/2GoP4lyRgU8yehiyYWBrSxsPPn1NERFEDHwJJPnzJz34FkN3TrnWJccNxHPmGNcC2lLMDCorXWelwn0ruGA8WpwseovOwnk1tZ6Tzje9@@C6H7Q998YrRSynmr2ejFpihjiCQitlUJBImQLr3esjTWzbzBiRivLwTzONhAFakljsm8qbWp8)):

```
64 64
64 64 64 56
56 56 63 63 63
63 63 64
66 66 66
```

```
[64, 64]
[64, 64, 64, 56]
[56, 56, 63, 63, 63]
[63, 63, 64]
[66, 66, 66]
```